# Can a runner run back to their original base after missing the latest base?

Tags: baseball

I have a question about baseball rules:

- R1 go to 3B base, R2 missed 3B, so R1 retreat to 3B and R3 touches 3B, in this case R2 can retreat to 2B and R1 can back to 2B or even 1B?